# In This Comparison, Are the Continents Moving Too Quickly?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, alternate-earth, tectonics

This is a map of one of my alternate Earths from 233 million years ago in comparison to a map of our Earth today:

[image]

And this is a map of the same alternate Earth, this time from 100 million years ago, again in comparison to a map of our Earth today:

[image]

Using the specified timeframe, would the continents be moving too quickly to be realistic?

Comment: Continents move at speeds of the order of centimeters per year. 2.5 cm/year (1 inch/year) is perfectly normal. Here is a [map of Earth](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pangaea_200Ma.jpg) 200 million years ago; as you can see, our Earthly continents have moved at about half the speed required by the question, which means that, yes, obviously, it is believable. (And notice how India has moved *faster* that what the question requires.)

Comment: It's very difficult to see your continents in the second picture, a higher contrast would make it easier. (Does this site have accessibility guidelines?)

Comment: @rek  Any better?  https://i.imgur.com/9Tw5f9g.png

Comment: Better. 7654321

Answer (score 3):

If you use as a reference our [planet history](https://sites.google.com/site/shawnhicksplatetectonics/continental-drift), it looks like the drift you have is plausible, or even slightly slower than our reference.

[image: continents position over time in Earth history]

I have some doubts about the borders of the continents in your world, since they seem to be less matching than what we see in our planet, but that can be explained by other causes and it's not in the scope of your question.